Unable to refresh session due to: Error authenticating with JWT
This error is printed to the Visual Studio Code Output window after I attempt to deploy an apex class with the SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org file option.
I have tried running the sf org login jwt command multiple times. The output is always like:
Successfully authorized username@domain.com with org ID 00DXXXXXXXXX
Everything was working fine until I authorized a new dev hub. How do you fix this error?

I would use the Authorize an Org command or sf org login web. I find it to be easier to use than using jwt auth.

After generating deployment manifest using sf project generate manifest
You can then use sf project deploy start -o <target-org> to deploy.
To learn more type sf commands to get a full list of commands available, for help on a particular command e.g. the deploy command type sf project deploy start --help

I have authorized the scratch org multiple times. It does not make a difference. The right-click option SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org still prints the error above
